# A Synced file between two sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, folder

First i have to say I am very new when it comes to Sharepoint but and a skilled developer.

I would like to sync a file between two different share sites.
The purpose for this is because we have a developers site which is private and then we have a public site that we have open. I would like the developers to be able to drop a file into a folder on their site and it show up on the public side.

Is this possible and if so how would i achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: both sites are in the same farm or same web application?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE What do you mean by that? Im not entirely familiar with those terms.

Comment: As You said about 2 sites...one on which developer woring & 2nd public facing site....my question what is environment  structure....are you using SharePoint  online/ office 365  ....or you have on premium SharePoint installation?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE we are currently on office365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [create SPItemEventReciver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx) to copy new file from development site to public site.

Comment: Can i do this if it is hosted on office 365?

Comment: In Sharepoint 2013 sandbox solutions are deprecated, so you can not create classic event reciever for sharepoint online. But I think you can create [remote event reciever](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220048(v=office.15).aspx) and copy files in custom web-service.