# How can I determine if the Document ID Service is enabled if I am not an admin?

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink

I want to make sure that I am not going to break existing links by renaming or moving files, so how do I know if the Document ID Service is enabled in SharePoint online, if I am not an admin.

I've read that the feature is configurable in the site settings, but it appear that you cannot even view the settings if you are not site collection admin.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-or-disable-site-collection-features-a2f2a5c2-093d-4897-8b7f-37f86d83df04?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

**Background**

I have not found Microsoft docs that talk about the durability of links. As an end user, how do I know if I have a durable link?

I have discovered through trial and error that **links to folders are NOT durable**.  If the folder is renamed or moved, then any existing links to the folder are broken. Is there a way to make links to folders durable?

Regarding files, I believe that **if Document ID Service is enabled, then links to files are durable**. File renames and moves within the site do not break existing links.

Comment: Related question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290085/durable-links-to-files-and-folders

Answer (score 1):

As you understand, if the **Document ID service** is enabled on the SharePoint site, then the file link(Document ID) is persistent. File renaming and movement within the site will not break existing links.

**Moving files with a Document ID:**

In SharePoint the Document ID will normally move with the file. However, when the destination site does not have the Document ID service enabled, the document will no longer have a Document ID.

**Copying files with a Document ID:**

When a copy of a file is made, a new Document ID is created for the copy. For example, a file downloaded from one site and uploaded to another is a copy. However, when the destination site does not have the Document ID service enabled, the copy will not have a Document ID.

For more information, please see "**[Enable and configure unique Document IDs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984)**" article.

Comment: This is very useful, but it doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [article](https://joannecklein.com/2018/11/16/sharepoint-online-and-document-id-the-goods/) which mentions the format of a URL using the Document ID:

https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[site]/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=1

Since it returns the following error message in my site, I assume this means that the Document ID Service is NOT enabled. I don't have a site where I know it is enabled in order to verify it.

> This Site Collection is not configured to use Document IDs.

[image]